# wordpress (avada) https: ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED on SOME resources

Tags: wordpress, docker, traefik

I am running three wordpress apps on a server, everything is configured with docker and traefik (https://traefik.io/) for hosting the code and forwarding to https. 
To archive correct resource forwarding in wordpress I setup the "home" and "siteurl" to my https domains.

It seems to work partially, I am struggling with a bug, where some of the resources cant be found. Here an example: one image, which is getting requested is: http://92.xx.xx.xx:xxxx/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/agency-seo-desk-front.jpg --> the ip and port are from the server and yes the correct WP app --> the correct request url should be: https://myDefinedURL.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/agency-seo-desk-front.jpg

The image cannot be found under IP and Port since traefik is configured to allow only https. 
This problem shows itself in all three of my apps: https://anotherAPP.com --> klick on menu item: "home" --> forward to serverIP and port... (wrong)

I hope this is clear, I am not sure where to set this additional IP, I tried the upload_url_path setting in wp_options too, it didnt help.

WP version 5.1
Avada version: 5.8.2

here the dco files app config:

```
  version: '3.4'
services:
#DATABASES 
  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7
    command: mysqld --character-set-server=utf8mb4 --collation-server=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./dbs/mysql/db:/var/lib/mysql
      - ./dbs/mysql_init:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
    ports:
      - 127.0.0.1:3306:3306
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD:  <hereIsACorrectMYSQLPW>
      MYSQL_USER:  <hereIsACorrectMYSQLUser>
      MYSQL_PASSWORD:  <hereIsACorrectPW>
#WORDPRESS
  <APPNAME>:
    build: ./wordpress/domain1/wordpress
    restart: always
    networks:
      - web
      - default
    volumes:
      - ./wordpress/app1/wordpress/data:/var/www/html/
      - ./wordpress/app1/uploads.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/uploads.ini
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    environment:
       SERVER_NAME: domain1.com
       WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: mysql:3306
       WORDPRESS_DB_USER:  <hereIsACorrectUserName>
       WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD:  <hereIsACorrectPW>
       WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: <hereIsACorrectDBName>
    labels:
      - "traefik.docker.network=web"
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.basic.frontend.rule=Host:domain1.com, www.domain1.com"
      - "traefik.basic.port=80"
      - "traefik.basic.protocol=http"
      - "traefik.frontend.redirect.entryPoint=https"
```

und traefik dco:

```
services:
  traefik:
    image: traefik:1.5.4
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    networks:
      - web
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - /opt/traefik/traefik.toml:/traefik.toml
      - /opt/traefik/acme.json:/acme.json
    container_name: traefik

networks:
  web:
    external: true
```

the traefik toml file:

```
debug = true

logLevel = "INFO"
defaultEntryPoints = ["https","http"]

[entryPoints]
  [entryPoints.http]
  address = ":80"
    [entryPoints.http.redirect]
    entryPoint = "https"
    regex = "^http://(www.)?(app1.net|app2.com|app3.com)/(.*)"
    replacement = "https://$1$2/$3"
    permanent = true
  [entryPoints.https]
  address = ":443"
    [entryPoints.https.tls]

[retry]

[docker]
endpoint = "unix:///var/run/docker.sock"
watch = true
exposedByDefault = false

[acme]
email = "meineEmail"
storage = "acme.json"
entryPoint = "https"
onHostRule = true
[acme.httpChallenge]
entryPoint = "http"
#[acme.tlsChallenge]
```

thanks a lot

best D